# How does Confluent Kafka Elasticsearch connector commits offset?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've been trying to configure Confluent Kafka Elasticsearch connector and it seems fine. 
The only question i can't find the answer about is how does this connector manages commits? 
What does it happen with data after [max.retries](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html) parameter is reached ?
Does offset rollback on Kafka's side?

Comment: Offsets don't rollback, they just aren't commited until a batch of messages are successfully written to Elasticsearch. Not sure that's what you're looking for

Comment: @cricket_007 , thanks for your response. That's exactly what I was looking for! May I ask you about one more thing? I'm trying to learn all the possibilities of the Elasticsearch-connect.properties file. I'm using [this] (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html)  doc. But I've found some other properties, for example "topics" and "topics.regex" and there is no such property in the doc. Where can I find any description about all properties, which could be mentioned in config file?

Comment: Those properties are inherent of all Kafka Connect plug-ins. Try searching the Apache Kafka site